# Elastic query & aggregations

Tags: elasticsearch, search, indexing, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am new to Elastic Search. I want to get the output from the `_source` of the query step to be included in the `aggs` step.

Example Data :

```
{
                    "id": "1",
                    "description": "nyHlUN4vLVT6cOjcM1xf",
                    "locationData": [
                        {
                            "locationId": "001-00001",
                            "delivery": true
                        },
                        {
                            "locationId": "001-00002",
                            "delivery": false
                        }
]}
```

Now I to get the output based id & locationId. For example for id='1' & locationId='001-00001' the output should be

```
{
                    "id": "1",
                    "description": "nyHlUN4vLVT6cOjcM1xf",
                    "locationData": [
                        {
                            "locationId": "001-00001",
                            "delivery": true
                        }
]}
```

It must not include the data with locationId equal to 001-00002.

I tried to use aggregation here but one more problem arise in this approach.
I got the locationData with only locationId equal to 001-00001 but the `id` & `description` was not included with `locationData`.

Here is the query which I used

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "id": {
                            "value": "1"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "filtered_locations": {
            "nested": {
                "path": "locationData"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "locations": {
                    "filter": {
                        "term": {
                            "locationData.locationId": "001-00001"
                        }
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "location_data": {
                            "top_hits": {
                                "_source": [
                                    "id",
                                    "description",
                                    "locationData"
                                ],
                                "size": 1
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone help on this or provide a documentation for such scenario ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need aggregation? You could recover through the [inner_hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/inner-hits.html).

The query would be this:

```
GET index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "id": {
              "value": "1"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "locationData",
            "inner_hits": {}, 
            "query": {
              "term": {
                "locationData.locationId.keyword": "001-00001"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Look to inner_hits:

```
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 1,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 0.98082924,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "index",
        "_id": "EIA4JIgBpLXl6DpqrRuF",
        "_score": 0.98082924,
        "_source": {
          "id": "1",
          "description": "nyHlUN4vLVT6cOjcM1xf",
          "locationData": [
            {
              "locationId": "001-00001",
              "delivery": true
            },
            {
              "locationId": "001-00002",
              "delivery": false
            }
          ]
        },
        "inner_hits": { <<--- your hit
          "locationData": {
            "hits": {
              "total": {
                "value": 1,
                "relation": "eq"
              },
              "max_score": 0.6931471,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_index": "index",
                  "_id": "EIA4JIgBpLXl6DpqrRuF",
                  "_nested": {
                    "field": "locationData",
                    "offset": 0
                  },
                  "_score": 0.6931471,
                  "_source": {
                    "delivery": true,
                    "locationId": "001-00001"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I am getting the output in aggregations but I also want id & description in the aggregation's output.